# XSL Add year to current date

Tags: xml, date, xslt

I want to add a year to the current date in XSL 2.0
I know how to get the current date:

```
<APPLIN_DT><xsl:value-fof select="format-date(current-date(), '[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]')"/></APPLIN_DT>
```

The current date also must be formatted like 'YYYY-MM-DD'
In an other element I need the currentdate + 1 year.
What is the best solution to do this?

Thanks!

Robert

Answer (score 5):

As you are using XSLT 2.0, try this...

```
<APPLIN_DT>
   <xsl:value-of select="format-date(current-date() + xs:yearMonthDuration('P1Y'), '[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]')"/>
</APPLIN_DT>
```

Where the namespace for the `xs` prefix is `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema`